# SqlAlchemy - How to query a table based on a key property saved as NestedMutableJson

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Let suppose a Postgres user table contains a property of type NestedMutableJson.

```
first_name character varying (120)
last_name character varying (120
country_info NestedMutableJson
...
from sqlalchemy_json import NestedMutableJson
country_info = db.Column(NestedMutableJson, nullable=True)
```

country_info = {"name": "UK", "code": "11"}

How to query the user table based on a country_info key.

POSTGRES Query

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE country_info ->> 'name' = 'UK'
```

Does any SqlAlchemy way give the same query result?

I tried several ways, example:

Way 1:

```
User.query.filter(User.country_info['name'].astext == 'UK').all()
```

Error:

```
Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression
```

Way 2:

```
User.query.filter(User.country_info.op('->>')('name') == 'UK').all()
```

Issue:

```
Always getting an empty response
```

I'm wondering if the issue caused by the column definition `db.Column(NestedMutableJson, nullable=True)`

> I'm avoiding using db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE country_info ->> 'name' = 'UK'").fetchall(). looking for something else

Answer (score 1):

simply user the ***text*** which allows you to write plain text filter inside orm process, it works like **get** function for a **dict**, and it can handle **None** fields also.

```
User.query.filter(text("COALESCE(user.country_info ->> 'name', '') = 'UK'")).all()
```

note that the name of the table should be the real name in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.op('->>')` to use the PostgreSQL operator `->>` in the following way:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine, String, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON
from sqlalchemy_json import NestedMutableJson

dburl = 'postgresql://...'
Base = declarative_base()

class CountryInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'country_info'
    id = Column(Integer, unique=True, nullable = False, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    country_info = Column(NestedMutableJson, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'CountryInfo({self.name!r}, {self.country_info!r})'

engine = create_engine(dburl, future=True, echo=True)

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    test = CountryInfo(name='test', country_info={"name": "UK", "code": "11"})
    test2 = CountryInfo(name='test2', country_info={"name": "NL", "code": "12"})
    test3 = CountryInfo(name='test3', country_info={"name": "UK", "code": "13"})

    session.add(test)
    session.add(test2)
    session.add(test3)
    session.commit()

    stmt = select(CountryInfo).filter(CountryInfo.country_info.op('->>')('name') == "UK")

    query = session.execute(stmt).all()
    for row in query:
        print(row)
```

This results in the following SQL:

```
SELECT country_info.id, country_info.name, country_info.country_info
FROM country_info
WHERE (country_info.country_info ->> %(country_info_1)s) = %(param_1)s
```

with `{'country_info_1': 'name', 'param_1': 'UK'}`

Which results in:

```py
(CountryInfo('test', {'name': 'UK', 'code': '11'}),)
(CountryInfo('test3', {'name': 'UK', 'code': '13'}),)
```

Comment: I have used that but I'm always getting an empty array even though I applied the same Postgres query and I'm getting the expected response. Maybe because my column is defined as the following `db.Column(NestedMutableJson, nullable=True)` ?

Comment: Question content has been updated @rfkortekaas

Comment: I've tested it with `NestedMutableJson` and get the same results...

Comment: @KhaledRamadan I've tested my example with `NestedMutableJson` (see change). The returned results are equal when using `JSON`. The example from Van doesn't work with `NestedMutableJson`.

Answer (score 0):

*Take a look at the [JSON](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON) datatype documentation.*

You should be able to do use this filter clause
`select(CountryInfo).filter(CountryInfo.country_info['name'].astext == "UK")`

Comment: I got this Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression, maybe because my column is defined as NestedMutableJson not sure.

Comment: Indeed it must be related to the `NestedMutableJson` being used and which implements all those operations as can be seen from the [code](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/json.py)

Comment: `astext` doesn't work with `NestedMutableJson`. When using type `JSON` this also works fine.